# useEffect "is called in function "onEachCountry" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function

Tags: json, reactjs, api

I'm trying to put the coronavirus cases by country in the popup line 42 on a planisphere map with geoJSON and the following api:
https://corona.lmao.ninja/v3/covid-19/countries
however that tells me the error " Line 23:3:   React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "onEachCountry" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter  react-hook"I call my api with axios and I use latest to index the data

do you have a solution ?

here my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import { Map, GeoJSON } from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import "./CovidMap.css";



const CovidMap = ({ countries }) => {
    const mapStyle = {
        fillColor: "white",
        weight: 1,
        color: "black",
        fillOpacity: 1,
    };

    const onEachCountry = (country, layer)=>{

 const [latest, setLatest] = useState([]);
 

  // connexion api 
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .all([
           //donnees par pays 
        axios.get("https://corona.lmao.ninja/v3/covid-19/countries"),
     
      ])
      .then(responseArr => {
        setLatest(responseArr[0].data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);


        layer.options.fillColor = country.properties.color;
        const name = country.properties.ADMIN; //parametrage popup pays 
        const cases = country.properties.cases;
            layer.bindPopup(`${name} ${latest.cases}`);
    }

    console.log(countries);
    return (
        <Map style={{ height: "90vh" }} zoom={2} center={[20, 100]}>
            <GeoJSON
                style={mapStyle}
                data={countries}
                onEachFeature={onEachCountry} />
        </Map>
    );
};

export default CovidMap;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `useEffect` in `onEachCountry` which is not allowed as seen by the error you are getting. Please refer to the React docs for more info. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html.

I think what you are trying for is the following:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import { Map, GeoJSON } from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import "./CovidMap.css";



const CovidMap = ({ countries }) => {
    const mapStyle = {
        fillColor: "white",
        weight: 1,
        color: "black",
        fillOpacity: 1,
    };

    const [latest, setLatest] = useState([]);

    // connexion API 
    useEffect(() => {
      axios
        .all([
           //donnees par pays 
          axios.get("https://corona.lmao.ninja/v3/covid-19/countries"),
     
          ])
          .then(responseArr => {
            setLatest(responseArr[0].data);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
     }, []);

   const onEachCountry = (country, layer)=> {
        layer.options.fillColor = country.properties.color;
        const name = country.properties.ADMIN; //parametrage popup pays 
        const cases = country.properties.cases;
        layer.bindPopup(`${name} ${latest.cases}`);
    }

    return (
        <Map style={{ height: "90vh" }} zoom={2} center={[20, 100]}>
            <GeoJSON
                style={mapStyle}
                data={countries}
                onEachFeature={onEachCountry} />
        </Map>
    );
};

export default CovidMap;
```

Comment: ty but in line 38 the editor still tells me that the case number is undefined : in my map and my card displays the name of the country selected with indefined after instead of the number of cases

Comment: @MendosaHenry following the get request to the endpoint above, it appears that `cases` is a key in the `countryInfo` object. I'm not sure exactly which line you are referring to but I assume you want something like `country.countryInfo.cases` instead of `country.properties.cases`.